# Calling virtual methods of different derived classes without instantiating

Tags: c++, casting, virtual

I have following class hierrachy:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void DoA();
    virtual void DoB();
    virtual void DoC();

protected:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void DoA() override;
    virtual void DoB() override;
    virtual void DoC() override;
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void DoA() override;
    virtual void DoB() override;
    virtual void DoC() override;
};
```

All of methods `DoA(), DoB()` ... operate only on members of base class,
and some of them might call base class methods inside of them. At runtime, I create object of type `DerivedA` as default, but I might need to change it to `DerivedB` or `DerivedC`. However I find it useless to create these object by copying state of `DerivedA` and initializing it again. I think the solution might be to cast `DerivedA` to any other type, but I'm not sure if it's safe and if it's a good design. Any opinions?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, you cannot cast "side-ways"

Comment: It's neither safe nor good design.

Comment: What's the difference between `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`? It sounds from your question like they are identical, but then there would be no reason for the distinct classes to exist. Can you elaborate on how they differ?

Comment: I would pleace you to read a beginner book of c++ and some tutorial stuff for OOP design. What you want to achieve and what you implement here seems to be not the way c++ can be used.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Perhaps you should let us know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For simplicity let's imagine those methods compute different types of bounding boxes... what's a good design then? I have a base class that basically holds the state and derived methods differ only in the way the use protected members to compute some operation, I think virtual methods are in place here. What I don't know is how to handle situation, that I might need to change type of the object during runtime, only to be able to use other derived class methods

Comment: @mezo You cannot change the type of an object. An object's type is the type it was given when it was initialized and that cannot be changed. Perhaps you want a second type of object that implements the desired functions and to which you can pass an object of the first type to act on. Then you could replace this second object with another to alter the behavior. I'm still not totally clear on what you want to do.

Comment: Imagine I;m trying to implement calculator, my base member class protected members are operands, and derived classes' member functions operates on them, but they do different operation. I could implement all methods in one class but semantically they are the same, a.k.a DerivedA::DoA() computes m_x+1, but DerivedB::DoA() computes m_x+2

Comment: @mezo It sounds like inheritance is the wrong approach for your problem. It seems you may want something like the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give sounds like you are trying to develop some sort of state machine with the different derived classes being different states. This is normally handled by using the letter/envelope idiom where the envelopes are the different states and the letter contains the common data.

```
#include <memory>
struct letter
{
   float m_x;
   float m_y;
};
class base_envelope
{
   std::unique_ptr< letter > data_;
   base_envelope( const base_envelope & ) = delete;
   base_envelope( base_envelope && ) = delete;
public:
   base_envelope(): data_() {};
   base_envelope( std::unique_ptr< letter > & d ): data_(std::move(d)) {}
   virtual void doA() = 0;
   virtual void doB() = 0;
   void swap( base_envelope & o ) { std::swap( data_, o.data_ ); }
};
class derived1: public base_envelope
{
public:
   derived1(): base_envelope() {}

   virtual void doA() override { }
   virtual void doB() override { }
   std::unique_ptr< base_envelope > change_state();
};

class derived2: public base_envelope
{
public:
   derived2(): base_envelope() {}

   virtual void doA() override {}
   virtual void doB() override {}
   std::unique_ptr< base_envelope > change_state()
   {
     std::unique_ptr< base_envelope > r( new derived1 );
     swap( *r );
     return std::move( r );
   }
};

std::unique_ptr< base_envelope > derived1::change_state()
{
  std::unique_ptr< base_envelope > r( new derived2 );
  swap( *r );
  return std::move( r );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should better have a pointer to `Base` class and create and assign an object of your derived class when you need:

```
Base * p = NULL;
// some code ...
p = new DerivedA;
p->DoA(); // DoA from DerivedA class
// some code ...
p = new DerivedB;
p->DoA(); // DoA from DerivedB class
```

Comment: You should avoid raw owning pointers. Notably, this example would leak the first `p`. They are generally a bad practice. Consider [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) in this case.

Comment: @mezo Are you saying your derived type stores a `unique_ptr` to itself? Or do you mean you bypass inheritance by including the "base" portion as a member?

Comment: Please use `nullptr` - we don't do that nasty `NULL` macro stuff any more. Besides, why not just initialize with something useful initially? Why even bother with the null assignment?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no, I store unique_ptr to Base in other class, let's call it class Object. In class Object, I want to cast member unique_ptr<Base> which has been assigned pointer to DerivedA, to pointer to DerivedB

Comment: @mezo It`s really bad idea, DerivedA and DerivedA is different objects